# Insert XML child node to SQL table

Tags: sql-server, xml, xpath, sql-server-2014, xquery

I've got an XML file like this and I'm working with SQL 2014 SP2

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<gwl>
<version>123456789</version>
<entities>
<entity id="1" version="123456789">
    <name>xxxxx</name>
    <listId>0</listId>
    <listCode>Oxxx</listCode>
    <entityType>08</entityType>
    <createdDate>03/03/1993</createdDate>
    <lastUpdateDate>05/06/2011</lastUpdateDate>
    <source>src</source>
    <OriginalSource>o_src</OriginalSource>
    <aliases>
       <alias category="STRONG" type="Alias">USCJSC</alias>
        <alias category="WEAK" type="Alias">'OSKOAO'</alias>
    </aliases>
    <programs>
        <program type="21">prog</program>
    </programs>
    <sdfs>
        <sdf name="OriginalID">9876</sdf>
    </sdfs>
    <addresses>
        <address>
            <address1>1141, SYA-KAYA STR.</address1>
            <country>RU</country>
            <postalCode>1234</postalCode>
        </address>
        <address>
            <address1>90, MARATA UL.</address1>
            <country>RU</country>
            <postalCode>1919</postalCode>
        </address>
    </addresses>
    <otherIds>
        <childId>737606</childId>
        <childId>737607</childId>
    </otherIds>
</entity>
</entities>
</gwl>
```

I made a script to insert data from the XML to a SQL table. How can I insert child node into a table? I think I should replicate the row for each new child node but i don't know the best way to proceed.

Here is my SQL code

```
   DECLARE @InputXML XML


   SELECT @InputXML = CAST(x AS XML)
   FROM OPENROWSET(BULK 'C:\MyFiles\sample.XML', SINGLE_BLOB) AS T(x)

    SELECT 
    product.value('(@id)[1]', 'NVARCHAR(10)') id, 
    product.value('(@version)[1]', 'NVARCHAR(14)')  ID
    product.value('(name[1])', 'NVARCHAR(255)') name,
    product.value('(listId[1])', 'NVARCHAR(9)')listId,
    product.value('(listCode[1])', 'NVARCHAR(10)')listCode,
    product.value('(entityType[1])', 'NVARCHAR(2)')entityType,
    product.value('(createdDate[1])', 'NVARCHAR(10)')createdDate,
    product.value('(lastUpdateDate[1])', 'NVARCHAR(10)')lastUpdateDate,
    product.value('(source[1])', 'NVARCHAR(15)')source,
    product.value('(OriginalSource[1])', 'NVARCHAR(50)')OriginalSource,
    product.value('(aliases[1])', 'NVARCHAR(50)')aliases,
    product.value('(programs[1])', 'NVARCHAR(50)')programs,
    product.value('(sdfs[1])', 'NVARCHAR(500)')sdfs,
    product.value('(addresses[1])', 'NVARCHAR(50)')addresses,
    product.value('(otherIDs[1])', 'NVARCHAR(50)')otherIDs

    FROM @InputXML.nodes('gwl/entities/entity') AS X(product)
```

Comment: Thx for the good question with sample data and own approach, +1 from my side

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a lot of **different children** here...

Just to show the principles:

```
DECLARE @xml XML=
N'<gwl>
  <version>123456789</version>
  <entities>
    <entity id="1" version="123456789">
      <name>xxxxx</name>
      <listId>0</listId>
      <listCode>Oxxx</listCode>
      <entityType>08</entityType>
      <createdDate>03/03/1993</createdDate>
      <lastUpdateDate>05/06/2011</lastUpdateDate>
      <source>src</source>
      <OriginalSource>o_src</OriginalSource>
      <aliases>
        <alias category="STRONG" type="Alias">USCJSC</alias>
        <alias category="WEAK" type="Alias">''OSKOAO''</alias>
      </aliases>
      <programs>
        <program type="21">prog</program>
      </programs>
      <sdfs>
        <sdf name="OriginalID">9876</sdf>
      </sdfs>
      <addresses>
        <address>
          <address1>1141, SYA-KAYA STR.</address1>
          <country>RU</country>
          <postalCode>1234</postalCode>
        </address>
        <address>
          <address1>90, MARATA UL.</address1>
          <country>RU</country>
          <postalCode>1919</postalCode>
        </address>
      </addresses>
      <otherIds>
        <childId>737606</childId>
        <childId>737607</childId>
      </otherIds>
    </entity>
  </entities>
</gwl>';
```

-The query will fetch some values from several places.
--It should be easy to get the rest yourself...

```
SELECT @xml.value('(/gwl/version/text())[1]','bigint') AS [version]
      ,A.ent.value('(name/text())[1]','nvarchar(max)') AS [Entity_Name]
      ,A.ent.value('(listId/text())[1]','int') AS Entity_ListId
      --more columns taken from A.ent
      ,B.als.value('@category','nvarchar(max)') AS Alias_Category
      ,B.als.value('text()[1]','nvarchar(max)') AS Alias_Content
      --similar for programs and sdfs
      ,E.addr.value('(address1/text())[1]','nvarchar(max)') AS Address_Address1
      ,E.addr.value('(country/text())[1]','nvarchar(max)') AS Address_Country
      --and so on
FROM @xml.nodes('/gwl/entities/entity') A(ent)
OUTER APPLY A.ent.nodes('aliases/alias') B(als)
OUTER APPLY A.ent.nodes('programs/program') C(prg)
OUTER APPLY A.ent.nodes('sdfs/sdf') D(sdfs)
OUTER APPLY A.ent.nodes('addresses/address') E(addr)
OUTER APPLY A.ent.nodes('otherIds/childId') F(ids);
```

The idea in short:

- We read non-repeating values (e.g. `version`) from the xml variable directly
- We use `.nodes()` to return repeating elements as derived sets.
- We can use a *cascade of `.nodes()`* to dive deeper into repeating child elements by using a *relativ Xpath* (no `/` at the beginning).

You have two approaches:

1. Read the XML like above into a staging table (simply by adding `INTO #tmpTable` before `FROM`) and proceed from there (will need one `SELECT ... GROUP BY` for each *type of child*).
2. Create one SELECT per *type of child*, using only one of the `APPLY` lines and shift the data into specific child tables.

I would tend to the first one.
This allows to do some cleaning, generate IDs, check for business rules, before you shift this into the target tables.